# How best to achieve automatic integer row version incrementation?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

So I have a model with an `int Version` property. I need it to be `int` and I need it to auto-increment each time I save, and I need it to throw if there is a concurrency error.

It cannot be a byte array nor a `DateTime`.

I have tried with `.IsRowVersion()`, but it doesn't seem to work on `int`. At least, it does absolutely nothing when used with `(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb`.

How can I best achieve automatic row version incrementation using EF Core + MSSQL? Perhaps I need to create some SQL triggers manually upon initialization?

Comment: @Larnu I think you misunderstood. This is a row versioning problem. I.e. when you update a row, the version should be incremented. Modifying the PK is something different :-)

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the actual [`rowversion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql) data type. It's not an `int` column.

Comment: Then what you want is `rowversion`, @HelloWorld ; which is a `binary(8)` value. If you have an arbitrary requirement like *"It cannot be a byte array nor a DateTime."* you need to elaborate on why, because `rowversion` is explicitly designed for what you seem to be after.

Comment: @Larnu I am interfacing with a 3rd party system, which requires versioning, which must be an integer.

Comment: @HelloWorld that's not what `rowversion` is for. If you want an incrementing number, use `IDENTITY`. A `rowversion` is **only** meant for implementing optimistic concurrency. It's not a database version, it's not related to time, it's certainly not a continuous value and isn't even guaranteed to be incrementing. It only needs to be *different from the previous value for the same row* to work.

Comment: If possible, I'd rather have the version exactly as it is in the 3rd party

Comment: @HelloWorld if you try to use a `rowversion` as a unique ID you'll find that the values jump and even be out of "sequence". If you try to use a "rowversion" to find changes you'll end up missing changes. That's not a bug - that's simply not what a `rowversion` is for. In any case you *can't* store your own value in a `rowversion` field. That value is controlled by the database

Comment: @Larnu no, I need to provide the version number. Seems like we are trying to adjust the question here to suit the solution, and not the other way around :-) My requirements are what they are. If there was any other way...

Comment: What is the actual requirement? A `rowversion` would work as an ETag, but that doesn't require incrementing anything.

Comment: @Larnu I am providing the version. My db.

Comment: What is the actual requirement? You're describing what you think the solution would look like, you aren't describing the problem. You can't modify a `rowversion` or change how it works.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos requirement is an int which increments. the new value must be greater than the old.

Comment: Again, that's not what `rowversion` does. It's not even a complete requirement, just a very small part of the requirement. Is this used as a *sequence* in messaging? Does it have to be unique across all rows? Different problems have different solutions. `update message set version=version+1 where ID=123` will increment the version just fine

Comment: @Larnu This is a complex system. My requirements are what they are. It would take too long to explain it fully here. I am using the version and the 3rd party is using the version. Stop arguing about me not needing the requirements. I know fully well that I need them :-)

Comment: We need them as well. Larnu isn't arguing. We've worked on message passing and complex problems too. We've actually attended Gregor Hohpe's talks on service integration before the book came out. We're telling you your question is incomplete and self-contradictory.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos uniqueness across rows is not required. yes, it is used as a sequence in messaging. it's a racing condition over a network whereby the receiving end will only accept the message if the version is greater than the old.

Comment: Don't mix up different concerns then. A row version isn't a sequence number. Use different fields for either. If you use `set seq=seq+1 where seq=@old_seq` you guarantee the sequence always increments. If you check the affected rows, or you use an `OUTPUT inserted.seq` clause to get the new sequence you'll be able to identify sequence errors (these aren't concurrency errors).

Comment: @Larnu two parties are synchronizing data. me and the 3rd party. the 3rd party will only accept the message if the new version is greater than the old. message order is not guaranteed. thus, a new version might be sent before an older one.

Comment: So are you saying you're trying to manage the row numbers in 2 separate environments, and *hoping* that they match? That isn't ever going to work; especially in an environment with a high volume of transactions. One side needs to handle to versioning, and pass that to the other end.

Comment: @Larnu no, only one environment can create, update, delete. anyways, was able to solve it. posted an answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Was able to solve this by marking the Version property with:

```
.HasDefaultValue(0).IsRowVersion()
```

And running the following SQL statement upon initialization:

```
var tableName = Model.FindEntityType(typeof(MyEntity)).GetTableName();
var sql =
$@"CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].Update{tableName}
ON [dbo].[{tableName}]
FOR  UPDATE
AS
UPDATE [{tableName}]
SET Version = [{tableName}].Version + 1
FROM [{tableName}]
INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON [{tableName}].Id = i.Id";

await Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(sql);
```